# Irrecognized Variable when calling

Tags: python-3.x, variables

Why it that preco is not recognized when used in python 3.11:

```
def desafio_2():
        global preco
        global qtd_carne 
        global tipo_carne 
        global nome 
        print(str('''
    1   FILE DUPLO R$4,9 por KG (até 5KG)|| R$5,80 (ACIMA DE 5KG) 
    2   alcatra    R$5,9 por KG (até 5KG)|| R$6,80 (ACIMA DE 5KG) 
    3   picanha    R$6,9 por KG (até 5KG)|| R$7,80 (ACIMA DE 5KG)   '''))
        tipo_carne =      print(int(input("Insira sua opcao: [1] [2] [3] ")))
        if (tipo_carne == 1):
            nome = "file duplo"
        elif(tipo_carne == 2):
            nome = "alcatra"
        elif(tipo_carne == 3):
            nome = "picanha"
        qtd_carne = print(float(input("Insira sua quantidade de carne em gramas:\n")))
        if(tipo_carne == 1):
            if(qtd_carne <=5):
                preco = qtd_carne * 4.90 / 1000
            else:
                preco = qtd_carne * 5.8 / 1000
        if(tipo_carne == 2):
            if(qtd_carne <=5):
                preco = qtd_carne * 5.90 / 1000
            else:
                preco = qtd_carne * 6.8 / 1000
        if(tipo_carne == 3):
            if(qtd_carne <=5):
                preco = qtd_carne * 6.90 / 1000
            else:
                preco = qtd_carne * 7.8 / 1000
                 
        tipo_pagamento = print(int(input("é Cartão débito [1] - (desconto 5%), Dinheiro Físico[2] \n")))
        if(tipo_pagamento == 1):
            preco = preco * 0.95
        else:
            preco = preco

        print("Relatório, preço", preco)
        print("TIPO DE CARNE:" , tipo_carne)
        print("QUANTIDADE EM KG:", qtd_carne)
        print("TIPO DE PAGAMENTO:", tipo_pagamento)
```

I tried to make a mini-market place where clients can get meat for a certain fixed price or with certain discounts given the KG number (<5 or >5)

None of the report (receipt info are being shown)

Comment: For debugging, use more `print`, and e.g. where you do not have a `else` print a diagnostic message. Also you use a strange syntax: do `x - int(input(...))` and in next line `print(x)`. Do not mix both

Answer (score 0):

answer:
You forgot to call the function and have to remove a tab from each line.

def desafio_2():
global preco
global qtd_carne
global tipo_carne
global nome
print(str('''
1   FILE DUPLO R$4,9 por KG (até 5KG)|| R$5,80 (ACIMA DE 5KG)
2   alcatra    R$5,9 por KG (até 5KG)|| R$6,80 (ACIMA DE 5KG)
3   picanha    R$6,9 por KG (até 5KG)|| R$7,80 (ACIMA DE 5KG)   '''))
tipo_carne =      print(int(input("Insira sua opcao: [1] [2] [3] ")))
if (tipo_carne == 1):
nome = "file duplo"
elif(tipo_carne == 2):
nome = "alcatra"
elif(tipo_carne == 3):
nome = "picanha"
qtd_carne = print(float(input("Insira sua quantidade de carne em gramas:\n")))
if(tipo_carne == 1):
if(qtd_carne <=5):
preco = qtd_carne * 4.90 / 1000
else:
preco = qtd_carne * 5.8 / 1000
if(tipo_carne == 2):
if(qtd_carne <=5):
preco = qtd_carne * 5.90 / 1000
else:
preco = qtd_carne * 6.8 / 1000
if(tipo_carne == 3):
if(qtd_carne <=5):
preco = qtd_carne * 6.90 / 1000
else:
preco = qtd_carne * 7.8 / 1000

```
tipo_pagamento = print(int(input("é Cartão débito [1] - (desconto 5%), Dinheiro Físico[2] \n")))
if(tipo_pagamento == 1):
    preco = preco * 0.95
else:
    preco = preco

print("Relatório, preço", preco)
print("TIPO DE CARNE:" , tipo_carne)
print("QUANTIDADE EM KG:", qtd_carne)
print("TIPO DE PAGAMENTO:", tipo_pagamento)
```

desafio_2()

Comment: Please [format your code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) properly.